# Why visual studio 2015 can not open blockchain api project on github

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, blockchain

Why visual studio 2015 can not open blockchain api project on github?
Her is the project's link :
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp

Here is the error :

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the solution file at api-v1-client-csharp/src/Info.Blockchain.API.sln in Github you see the following line

```
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
```

Version 15 of visual studio is Visual Studio 2017 which means this solution requires Visual Studio 2017.